# Was there a GOLEM?

Tags: history, practical-kabbalah, myths, artificial-lifeform

was there really a golem made in Prague that was alive and interacted with other people?

I heard that this story was nothing more than a made up tale in a children's book. Does anyone know the real history behind it? What evidence do we have backing it up? Is it brought down in any written authoritative source?

Comment: The Golem from the Prague I believe has no clear source to back it up.however there is an idea of a golem. In the Talmud Sanhedrin 65b Rava makes a man and sends it to Rav Zeira.Rav Zeira proceeds to talk to it but it does not respond so Rav Zeira realized a Chacham made it and he destroyed it(seems evident a golem can't speak).There is another account brought down by Rav Tzvi Askenazi (Chacham Tzvi) shelot and tshuvot 93 with a golem .

Comment: In Search of EMeTh, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Rav Hutner said I dont Understand the big Deal I Made plenty of golems look at some of the talmidim who came out of my yeshiva

Comment: @sam the question seems to be specifically about the one by the Maharal

Comment: Why can't they send a robot with a camera to the attic??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main original source talking about the Golem was the [Niflaos Maharal](http://hebrewbooks.org/4139) published in 1909. It claims to have been written by the son-in-law of the Maharal (R' Yitzchok Katz) and was kept in the library in Metz, until (after being in the hands of some middle-men) it was discovered by R' Yudel Rosenberg of Warsaw. R' Rosenberg claims that the Noda Biyehuda went to the attic where the Golem lies (although he asked ten of his students to say Tehillim for him at the time, because of the danger).

However, ([R'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Judah_Loeb_Rapoport)) [Shlomo Rappoport](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6757&st=&pgnum=54) says that the Maharal never created a Golem, and the stories are forgeries.

[R' Shwartz](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13302&st=&pgnum=41) also mentioned a proof to the fact that the Maharal did not create a Golem, in that no Rabbinic historian of his time mentioned the Golem. Neither the Chida nor the Tzemach Dovid (who was a student of the Maharal and wrote a sefer on Jewish history) wrote that the Maharal made a Golem.

However,  R' Shwartz points outs that the ֲBnei Yissochor wrote that the Maharal used to use Sefer Yetzira (the Kabbalistic work discussing the creation of Golems) and the Imrei Yosef (the Rebbe from Spinka) quotes the Niflaos Maharal (obviously being of the opinion that it's a legitimate sefer).

Moreover, he writes that it in Megilas Yuchsin (written and published in 1864, some forty years before Niflaos Maharal) that the Shoel Umeishiv (who was alive when this sefer was published) went to Prague and wanted to go to where the Golem lies. The Gabbai told him that before the Noda BeYehuda went up there, he fasted and went went to Mikva, then he wrapped himself in a Tallis and Tefillin and went up. When he came down, he said that no one else should go up there.

So R' Shwartz answers that it's possible that the Maharal created this golem for a short period of time and then destroyed it. However, people made up rumors about it.

Comment: of interest: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2010/05/golem-of-prague-in-recent-rabbinic.html and story #8 here: http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/proceeding-together-1/02.htm

Comment: "ten of his students to say Tehillim for him." - do you mean for the Golem?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What does the fact that the Noda Biyehuda went to the attic have to do with saying Tehillim for him?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin So to clarify: R' Yudel Rosenberg is the one who claimed that the Noda Biyehuda went to the attic. R' Rosenberg therefore instructed his own students to say Tehillim for the Noda Biyehuda. Did I get that right?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I see where I got confused. I edited it to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Is learning Sefer Yetzira such a proof? Don't lots of kabbalists learn that book? (I really have no idea.)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Ahh you mean BY writes that MHRL actually _used_ it. I understand the proof now.

Comment: In addition to the golem story, R' Yehuda Yudel Rosenberg was responsible for a number of Maharal related forgeries, including another story about the Maharal and the Choshen Mishpat (based upon a story by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle titled, "The Jew's Breastplate") and the notorious Maharal haggada. It is unfortunate that he engaged in forgery (especially the latter, the first two could have been misunderstood attempts at historical fiction), as R' Rosenberg was clearly a very knowledgeable man with a great deal to offer. (His Zohar Torah remains popular to this day.)

Comment: Is this the Imrei Yosef you refer to? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Meir_Weiss It says he died in 1909. How could he quote a book published in 1909?

Comment: Lubavitcher Rebbe writes the his father-in-law (Sixth Lubavitcher Rebbe) told him that when he went up into the attic he saw the remnants of the Golem: http://www.rabbiyehudahyudelrosenberg.com/pdf/primary3.pdf

Comment: Attached is a copy of a page given out at a Rosenberg family event. I received it in a shiur given about the Golem (which had the same conclusion as R' Schwartz). IIRC from the shiur it was R Rosenberg himself or his children who published the packet. In it is some biographical info about the Rosenberg family, and most interestingly, a complete admittance that several of R' Rosenberg's works are complete fiction, including the Niflaos Hamaharal; and even his Raziel Hamalach, all of which are Folk-literature. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HUQuvCl4TiQaTiMetLN13NmkR2Jkz4wC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, yeah, my mistake

Comment: but the point is, this teshura basically ends the conversation on the legitimacy of niflaos hamaharal

Comment: IIRC, his intention was to write "kosher" fiction stories for Jews, to read instead of secular literature